# How to test GraphQL queries with fragments using jest

Tags: graphql, jestjs, graphql-js, graphql-tag

Problem: I would like to test a GraphQL query that lives in a `.graphql` file like this:

```
#import '../../fragments/Widget.graphql'

query WidgetFragment($id: ID) {
    readWidgetFragment(id: $id) {
        ...Widget
    }
}
```

To create a GraphQL schema with mocked resolvers and data, I use  `makeExecutableSchema` and `addMockFunctionsToSchema` from [graphql-tools](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools).

To run the query from inside a jest test, my understanding is that I need to use the `graphql()` function from [graphql-js](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql/#graphql).

This function needs the query as a **string**, so I tried two different ways, but neither of them worked:

- Parse the `.graphql` file as a normal text file, giving me the raw string (using the [jest-raw-loader](https://github.com/keplersj/jest-raw-loader) in my jest config).
  This gives me: `Failed: Errors in query: Unknown fragment "Widget".` when I run the query.
- Parse the `.graphql` file into a `query` object using [jest-transform-graphql](https://github.com/remind101/jest-transform-graphql). I believe this should be the right approach, because it *should* resolve any imported fragments properly. However, to execute the query, I need to pass `query.loc.source.body` to the `graphql`, which results in the same error message as option 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import { print } from 'graphql/language/printer'

import query from './query.gql'

...

print(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the initial approach with parsing it as a raw text, except:

1. use a recursive function with a path argument  (assuming you could have nested fragments)
2. which uses [regex](https://regex101.com/r/8sWPjm/3) to extract all imports beforehand to an array (maybe use a nicer pattern :) )
3. append the rest of the file to a string variable
4. then loop through imports, resolving the `#import`s and passing them to itself and appending the result to the string variable
5. Finally return the result to the main function where you pass it to the `graphql()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite a pickle. Even with imports correctly working (>= v2.1.0 for [jest-transform-graphql](https://github.com/remind101/jest-transform-graphql), they get added to the `query.definitions` object, which is completely sidestepped when calling `graphql` with `document.loc.source.body` as query argument.

On the server end, graphql [(`function graphqlImpl`)](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/graphql.js#L182) will reconstruct the `document` object using `parse(source)` - but it'll have zero knowledge of the imported fragment definitions...

As far as I can tell, the best bet is to stamp fragments to the query source before sending it to the server. You'll need to explicitly find all lines starting with `#import` and replace these with actual text content of the to-be-imported `graphql` file.

Below is the function that I use. (Not tested for recursive fragments)

```js
// Async wrapper around dynamic `import` function
import { importQuery } from "./queries";

const importAndReplace = async (fileToImport, sourceDocument, line) => {
  const doc = await importQuery(fileToImport);
  const targetDocument = (await sourceDocument).replace(line, doc.loc.source.body);
  return targetDocument;
};

// Inspired by `graphql-tag/loader` 
// Uses promises because of async function `importQuery` used
export default async graphqlOperation => {
  const { body } = graphqlOperation.loc.source;
  const lines = body.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
  const bodyWithInlineImports = await lines.reduce(
    async (accumulator, line) => {
      await accumulator;
      const lineSplit = line.slice(1).split(" ");

      return line[0] === "#" && lineSplit[0] === "import"
        ? importAndReplace(lineSplit[1].replace(/"/g, ""), accumulator, line)
        : Promise.resolve(accumulator);
    },
    Promise.resolve(body)
  );
  return bodyWithInlineImports;
};
```